# Gwidgets Radio Buttons

Tags: r, gwidgets

I want to make a GUI using the Gwidgets package in R. I have a piece of code that generates a list which I then want to put as radio buttons in my GUI to let the user select some options. A basic example of what I am trying to achieve is attached

```
library(gWidgets)
library(tcltk2)
options("guiToolkit"="tcltk")
win <- gwindow("Test", visible=TRUE)
l <- gframe(container=win)
z <- ggroup(container = l)
gradio(item=c("Coffee", "Straw"), container=z)
gradio(item=c("tea", "Vanilia"), container=z)
```

How do I return a list of the checked options for the gradio items? That is if I have multiple radio buttons how do I get the values of each. In this case if Coffee and Vanilia are selected how do I get these values. Something like svalue(z) does not work?

Comment: I got something to work here. Basically store the gradio as a list then using sapply(list.name, svalue) works

Comment: Yup, that's it. If you have simple layout, you can create that list using lapply, or some such, during construction.